# Avoiding duplicate long expressions in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I often find myself writing Excel formulas that have something like this in the formula:

```
= IF(<long expression>=<some condition>,<long expression>,0)
```

Is there any way to accomplish this without needing to type out `<long expression>` twice (and also without using helper cells)?

Ideally, something that works similar to `IFERROR`, i.e.

```
= IFERROR(<some expression>,0)
```

This checks if `<some expression>` would return any type of error, and if it doesn't, it automatically returns `<some expression>` (without needing to again explicitly type it out a second time).

Is there an Excel function (or combination of Excel functions) similar to `IFERROR` but instead of checking an error condition, it checks a general (user-defined) condition based on the formula?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665435/how-do-i-avoid-repeating-long-formulas-in-excel-when-working-with-comparisons

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks Scott, interesting solution. However, this only works for expressions that return a number. Any thoughts for a more general approach (e.g. for expressions that return text)?

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359452/if-function-is-there-a-way-to-avoid-repeating-formula

Comment: no, and is why I did not mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks anyway. I'm not too excited about using the `EXP(LN(...))` approach, especially for integers, because `LN()` would return a floating point and `EXP()` of that may not return the exact desired result. (e.g. it could return 5.000000001 instead of just 5, not those exact numbers but something along those lines).

Comment: Then the best method is to put the formula in another cell and refer to that twice.

Comment: Or write your own UDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to formula efficiency and calculation speed, using helper cells can be of great value, even if they may initially muck up the spreadsheet design.

Put calculations into a helper cell and refer to the helper cell in the IF statement. That way the calculation will only happen once.

This method is preferred by spreadsheet auditors over the alternative of packing everything into one formula, because it is also much easier to follow and pick apart.

With careful spreadsheet planning you can house helper cells in a different (hidden) sheet or in columns that you hide to tidy up the design.

Comment: "careful spreadsheet planning" - how many times have I had to change to accommodate revisions ... Good advice!

Comment: I guess I always consider it a personal challenge to accomplish anything without helper rows, but I never really considered the fact that I may be making it less efficient. This is good advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This answer applies to Excel 365 as of March 2020. A new function is now available in Insider builds of Excel. It is called LET() and is used to define, and assign a value to, a variable that can then be used multiple times inside the braces of the LET() function.

Example:

```
=LET(MyResult,XLOOKUP(C1,A1:A3,B1:B3),IF(MyResult=0,"",MyResult))
```

The first parameter is the name of a new variable, `MyResult`. The variable is assigned a value with the second parameter. This can be a constant, like a number or a text, or like in this case, a formula.

The third parameter is a calculation that can use the variable value.

In the following screenshot, the Xlookup returns a 0 because the found cell is empty.

In the next formula down, the Xlookup is wrapped in an IF statement, evaluated, and then repeated. This is the approach where the calculation is duplicated, as described in the question.

The third formula shows the LET() function and its result.

[image]